# How can I get current URL using smarty

Tags: smarty

How to get `URL` using `Smarty` similar to `window.location` in `JavaScript` ?

I did this

```
{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF}
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You can use this, too.

```
{$smarty.server.HTTP_HOST}{$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: This might cause some security issues if the user tampers the header fields: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php

Comment: yes yes it has security risk and not compatible with https.

Comment: also you can look at here:
http://www.reddit.com/r/netsec/comments/1dhpiy/practical_http_host_header_attacks/

Answer (score 5):

See what is available with this:

```
{$smarty.server|@var_dump}
```

A couple examples for url **https://some.example.com/some/path?param=1**:

```
{$smarty.server.SCRIPT_URI}
```

https://some.example.com/some/path

```
{$smarty.server.SERVER_NAME}
```

some.example.com

```
{$smarty.server.SCRIPT_URL}
```

/some/path

Answer (score 3):

This is controller code :

```
<?php
require_once('libs/Smarty.class.php');
$smarty = new Smarty();
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && $_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {
    $pro = 'https';
} else {
    $pro = 'http';
}
$port = ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] == "80") ? "" : (":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]);
$current_url =  $pro."://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$port.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$smarty->assign("current_url",$current_url);
$smarty->display('index.tpl');

?>
```

You can display variable in index.tpl template file :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        {$current_url}

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is simple PHP file , no need to worry , you can use this code directly